# Trying to get .modal('show') to slide element in from the right as opposed to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've been tasked with changing a modal's direction of entry from the (apparent) default of top to appearing from the right. Here is the js at the moment:

```
$(function () {
        $('#FbButtonLink').on('click', function () {
            $('.modal-content').load(this.href, function () {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#FeedbackForm');
                $('#Fb-ErrorMessage').hide();
                $('#modal-container').modal('show');
                $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
                $('#FeedbackForm').submit(function () {
                    if ($('#FeedbackForm').valid()) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: this.action,
                            type: this.method,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                if (result.success) {
                                    $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                                } else {
                                    $('#Fb-ErrorMessage').text("System error, please try again.");
                                    $('#Fb-ErrorMessage').show();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                $('#Fb-ErrorMessage').text("Network error, please try again.");
                                $('#Fb-ErrorMessage').show();
                            },
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

$('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#modal-container').show('slide', { direction: 'right' });
});

$('#modal-container').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 'slow');
});
```

I did not write this code, but I've been looking at it for a while (and searching ".modal('show')") but I can't make sense of it.

```
<div id="FbLink">
    <a id="FbButtonLink" href="/CL/Home/AddFeedback" class="btn button-big">
         <span>Feedback</span>
         <span class="fa fa-commenting">
             <svg>
                 <use xlink:href="~/Areas/CL/Content/app/images/icons/icon-svg-defs.svg#fa-commenting" />
             </svg>
         </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="ModalPartial">
    <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
             <div class="modal-content">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

How does the .modal('show'); line call the .on('modal.bs.show') function? Or doesn't it? Because, at the moment, **this code still has the feedback form element appearing from the top, as opposed to the right, as intended.**

Any pointers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code to make the modal appear from right :-

```
.modal.fade:not(.in) .modal-dialog {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but that appears to have worked! Thanks!

Comment: @moosefetcher- You are welcome. I am glad that my answer helped you in some way.